# How to put XFBML code by ajax?

Tags: ajax, facebook, dom, xfbml

I would like to use javascript (JQuery) to ask the server for XFBML code via ajax.
The XFBML code will then attached to the DOM.

Here it is the php code:

```
echo "
<fb:serverFbml>
    <script type=text/fbml'>
    <fb:fbml>
        <fb:request-form
            action='http://myserver.com/invited.php'
            method='post'
            type='myserver'
            invite='true' 
            content='yo you...'>
            <fb:request-form-submit uid=12312312label='Send to %n ' import_external_friends=false />
        </fb:request-form>
        </fb:fbml>
  </script>
</fb:serverFbml>

";
```

and here is the javascript:

```
function clickME() {

    $.ajax(
            {
                url:'http://myserver.com/fbml_ajax.php',
                success:attachData,

                type:'GET',
                dataType:'html',
                global:false
            }
        );

}

function attachData(data) {
    var myData = data;
    $('#attachnow').html(data);
}
```

I can't make it work.. it is not attached.
If I just put the XFBML staticly on the HTML page, it works. but if I attach to DOM it doesn't.

Is it because of the  tag? or is it because of the data that contains \r\n when return from from server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [FB.XFBML.parse](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) on any new content. FBML is only parsed on page load by default. According to the second example in the page I linked, the exact code would be

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('attachnow'));
```

added as the last line of your `attachData` function.

Comment: so, should I run FB.xFMBL.parse(data)  on the data passed back by ajax right away, or attach to dom, then run FB.XBML.parse('attachnow') ?

Comment: @murvinlai - after attaching to the DOM. Rationale: The FB code dealing with the element in the DOM (e.g. "document.getElementById") - so you need to do your processing and attach the item to the DOM and THEN call FB to parse your added content.